# How To Start to Educate Yourself in Film Making?

Tags: recommendation

I am interested in making films, movies or documentaries but for several years I believed that I needed to watch a lot of movies and documentaries from all around the world. I am 23 and watched apprx. 480 productions (movies and documentaries) with paying attention to the style of different directors in making movies.

I am from Turkey and as a start I want to educate myself in film making then make a project about the education system in some local universities in our country. I want this project, which will be sort of documentary, to be good quality by cinematography, sound, shooting techniques, edit, music. Not to mention it will be a non-profit work.

#### Question:

I found a local film making school which requires around $300 for 2 weeks education for directing and film making course. Since I will finance the project and desire to direct it with my poor technical knowledge at present. Since, I want to attend a school like this. Is this a useful start and what is your advice? I hope my question is not going to seem foolish.

Comment: Whether or not it is useful is not something we can tell you here. Experience is a good thing, sure, but it'll be up to you whether you find that useful.

Comment: There are loads and loads of free filmmaking websites, videos, tutorials etc online, Vimeo have free videos which teach you loads of basic things, Youtube offers tonnes of videos from other filmmakers. websites like NoFilmSchool are a great place to learn loads, in the end it is how you take the info and use it to your advantage, otherwise just make films and learn from them